# PHP - Pass Argument to class __construct on call?

Tags: php, class, call

```
class Portfolio extends Rest{   
    public $pdo;
    public $lanx;

    public function __construct($uid, $langx){
        $this->lanx = $langx;
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $this->pdo = $db->getConnection();
    }
```

When I call a function from `Portfolio`

```
Portfolio::newItem();
```

how can I pass `$uid` and `$langx` to the class?

Comment: Your constructor doesn't use `$uid` parameter, why is that?

Comment: `Portfolio::newItem();` is calling the method statically - you're not creating a new instance of `Portfolio` so the constructor isn't being called. Create a new Portfolio object first (with the instantiation parameters) like `$p = new Portfolio($uid, $langx)` then call the newItem method of that object `$p->newItem()` ... unless there's a Singleton or Factory pattern that we can't see.

Comment: i have removed some of the code Jack. I created a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Portfolio $p = new newItem($uid, $langx);
```

Comment: Are you thinking of another language?

Comment: Not far off `$p = new Portfolio($uid, $langx)`

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: im sorry, I was thinking in java!

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = new MyClass($param1, $param2);
```

Just do it like calling a function. Also take note of the "required" and "optional" parameters for that construct.

Answer (score 0):

Its a better option to invoke static method with parameters like this:

```
Portfolio::newItem($uid, $langx);
```

in Method Definition:

```
public static function newItem($uid = null, $langx = null) {
    //Check Vars are set or not if not set them 
    //If all vars passed null and not sett in class throw exception
}
```